# how to dispose/kill a page in a PageView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a PageView with 2 pages, I have a custom stack of navigator for each of both pages.

At the initial start(let's say I star on page 1), page 2 is built when I start scrolling or jump to it (as normal).

thought when I am on page 2 and go back to page 1 and vice-versa, the pages are kept alive and I would like to dispose/kill them to force a rebuild..at least on page 2.

I tried `wantKeepAlive = false` but doesn't work.

can someone share a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

#### Rebuild on Swipe

If the goal is to tell our widgets to rebuild when pages are swiped back/forth, we can use the `onPageChanged` callback of `PageView.builder`.<sup>1</sup>

`onPageChanged:` will run the function we give it each time a page is viewed.

#### Linking `onPageChanged` to Rebuild Pages

There's no built-in connection between `onPageChanged` and rebuilding of pages in a `PageView`.

`onPageChanged` just runs **any** arbitrary function we give it, nothing more.

If we wish to rebuild pages with `onPageChanged` we need to create that linkage ourselves.

#### Link with `ValueNotifier`/`ValueListenableBuilder`

In this example, we're using `ValueNotifier` (the `buildCount` variable) to notify the `ValueListenableBuilder` to rebuild whenever `buildCount` changes. (See [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) for info.)

Each time we swipe pages the `buildCount` will increment and the `ValueListenableBuilder` in our pages will rebuild, displaying the new total:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageViewRebuildPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PageView Stream Rebuild'),
      ),
      body: PageViewRebuildExample()
    );
  }
}

class PageViewRebuildExample extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> contents = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  final ValueNotifier<int> buildCount = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Example built');
    return Center(
      child: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: contents.length,
        onPageChanged: (page) {
          print('PageChanged $page');
          buildCount.value++;
        },
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40, horizontal: 20),
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: buildCount,
                    // bldCnt here ↓↓ is buildCount.value
              builder: (context, bldCnt, child) =>
                  // ↓ YOUR STUFF GOES HERE ↓
                  Text('Page ${contents[index]} : $bldCnt',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To adapt this example for your purposes, you'd replace the `builder:` part of `ValueListenableBuilder` with your Widget.  It will be rebuilt on each swipe.

---

#### Addendum

If you want to know the precise position of a page during a swipe gesture we can provide a `PageController` to `PageView`, attach a listener to that controller, and listen to the `controller.page` output:

```
class PageViewRebuildExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageViewRebuildExampleState createState() => _PageViewRebuildExampleState();
}

// Switched to StatefulWidget so we can add listener & dispose
class _PageViewRebuildExampleState extends State<PageViewRebuildExample> {
  final List<String> contents = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  final ValueNotifier<int> buildCount = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final PageController controller = PageController(); // ← our new controller

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() { // ← add a listener in onInit
      print('Precise page position ${controller.page}');
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose(); // don't forget to dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Example built');

    return Center(
      child: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: contents.length,
        controller: controller, // ← PageController provided here
        onPageChanged: (page) {
          print('PageChanged $page');
          buildCount.value++;
        },
```

The output from our example listener above is (snipped to shorten):

```
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.001861572265625
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.006500244140625
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.01019287109375
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.012054443359375
... <snip>
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.45981356897799835
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.5179874247450384
I/flutter (14528): PageChanged 1
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.5743095749455654
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.6269737660740682
... <snip>
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.9986377335325707
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.9988375372072605
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 0.9990080727700607
I/flutter (14528): Precise page position 1.0
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There are likely many other ways to do this, this is just one method. For example, using `Stream` to send events from `onPageChanged` to a `StreamBuilder` inside `itemBuilder` is another.

Comment: and how can I correct the `onPageChanged` that triggers when you scroll past the middle of the screen, to trigger on scroll starts.

Comment: also by curiosity, do you know the logic used to dismiss widgets that are not visible in the viewport in the `.builder()` method. that idea seemed more suitable though

Comment: @bihireboris Not sure I follow your first comment question.  If you need fine-grained control of page swipe (i.e. precise position during a scroll gesture) we can use a `PageController` and its `page` property.  I'll add that as an addendum to answer.

Comment: @bihireboris For your 2nd comment, I'm not directly familiar with the disposal logic on `PageView`.  You'll have to browse the SDK definition of `PageView` for that.